# Programs Working Together

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple command-line board game in Ruby. I need to have main game code and then independent code for the two players that are going to be written by two different people or teams. So the main game needs to allow different players to play without changing any code.

I've been thinking of ways to do this, but this is the biggest programming project I've ever undertaken and I frankly don't have a good Idea yet.

Should both player-programms define a method that the main game calls? Should I have a Player class and have the player-Programms subclass it? I tried a few things but it never seems to be what I was looking for or what would be considered even decent design.

What would be a good way to do this in Ruby (or any other language, as the problem is a general programming problem)?

I hope I was able to phrase the question correctly.

Comment: Are the player programs being `require`ed, or are they separate processes?

Comment: I don't know. I could have a standard file name that player1.rb and player2.rb and require them. But I rather would use something else, like the way Aasmund Eldhuset suggested. I would like have different AIs and let them play each other. What would you suggest?

Comment: If playing the game only consists of one or two times when the player needs to be polled, you could use lambdas or method objects. That would be a little easier. Or you could use the `load(file, true)` approach for sand boxing code. Or you could run them as separate Ruby threads with lowered privileges and query them through some agreed on variable. It really depends on the number of communications between your software and the playing software.

Comment: There are things remaining to be defined: Are the games being played locally on a shared host?, or played on separate machines on a LAN?, or across the internet? Those bring different needs and rule out certain ways of going about this. At a minimum I'd not use `require`. Provide a RPC or HTTP-based API that they have to write to. Be defensive, no, paranoid, by checking all your inputs for size and correctness.

Comment: It's a pretty simple setup: Everything is local. Teams can decide to be the detective or the criminal. Then they write their code. And then the main game code, sets everything up and checks each player in turn for a move and updates the game state until the game is finished. Of course the player codebases need to know about gamestate changes too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the subclass approach sounds good (in other languages, interfaces might be a better choice, but I don't think interfaces exist in Ruby). The method that each player class must implement should take as a parameter an object that contains the entire game state (such as the piece positions if you are making chess). This object must be read-only or must be a copy of the game state, so that the player classes may not directly alter the game state. Instead, the method that the player classes must implement should return some value that indicates what move the player wishes to do. I suppose that Ruby supports some mechanism to dynamically instantiate a class from another file based on the names of the class and the file. You could start the game like this, using parameters to indicate the file and class names:

```
ruby game.rb player1.rb Player1Class player2.rb Player2Class
```

The game would probably look like this pseudocode:

```
gameState = createObjectDescribingInitialGameState()
player1FileName = args[0]
player1ClassName = args[1]
player2FileName = args[2]
player2ClassName = args[3]
player1 = dynamicallyInstantiateClassFromFile(player1ClassName, player1FileName)
player2 = dynamicallyInstantiateClassFromFile(player2ClassName, player2FileName)
currentPlayer = player1
while not gameState.isGameOver():
    move = currentPlayer.makeMove(gameState.createReadOnlyCopy())
    gameState.peformMove(move)
    currentPlayer = player2 if currentPlayer == player1 else player1
```

With this approach, you can write the core game code once and launch it without modification with any pair of player classes.